# Image loader isn't displayed

Tags: jquery, image, loader

I want to display a background image (loading.gif) while the image is loading. The image loads thanx to the following code :

```
var item = $('<li><a class="black-links" href="' + data.url + '#comments" title="' + data.title + '"><img class="loading"></a></li>');
var img = item.find('img');
img
    .hide()
    .one('load', function() { $(this).removeClass('loading').attr('alt', data.title).attr('width', data.width).attr('height', data.height).fadeIn(); })
    .attr('src', data.src)
    .each(function() { if (this.complete) $(this).trigger('load'); });
```

So there's a "loading" class added to the image at the beginning, and then this class is removed once the image is entirely loaded (and displayed). So the CSS code is :

```
.loading { background: #FFF url(../img/loading.gif) center center no-repeat; }
```

The trouble is : the image is loaded, and then it's displayed, BUT the loader is never displayed while the image is loading (this can be seen [here](http://www.mediatheque-erre.fr/test/)).
I thought I should delete the ".hide()"... but then I think the image will be partly displayed BEFORE it's entirely loaded, won't it ???

Thanx for your help !

Comment: Load the img first (with new image), then append it. That way, you can display a spinner while loading.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what I should change precisely...

Comment: Well, if you create an image, load it then append it, you don't have to hide the <img>, so you can display the spinner. Other solution : add the spinner in another element with some CSS.

Comment: So could I only change the last part, like this ? img.one('load', function() { $(this).attr({src: data.src, alt: data.title, width: data.width, height: data.height}).fadeIn(); }).attr('src', '../img/loading.gif').each(function() { if (this.complete) $(this).trigger('load'); }); Would this be fine ???

Comment: You calling each when you have only one element.

Comment: That's because I've been told that the ".load" function sometimes isn't triggered as it should...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you hide it when it's loaded

```
var item = $('<li><a class="black-links" href="' + data.url + '#comments" title="' + data.title + '"><img class="loading"></a></li>');
var img = item.find('img');
$('<img/>').attr('src', data.src).load(function() {
      img.removeClass('loading').attr('src', data.src).hide().fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: But this whole thing look like it belong to the loop over data `for (var i in result) { var data = result[i]; ...`

Comment: It's not the same, you have hiden (Outside the DOM) image, and you attached load event to it (so it's executed when it's loaded) and main (visible) image is changed when this hidden is loaded. And your code add src to hidden element. If you hide something it will be hidden ;)

Comment: Mmm... not sure to understand (sorry, I'm far to be a pro as you can see) : shouldn't it be `img.attr etc.` instead of `$('<img/>').attr etc.` ?

Comment: It's different element, new one, which have load attached. It's not displaying on the page you set img.attr when this hidden image is loaded. 2 images.

Comment: So, let me see if I understand well what you mean : is the following code correct ? $('<img/>')
 .one('load', function() { img.removeClass('loading').attr({src: data.src, alt: data.title, width: data.width, height: data.height}).fadeIn(); })
 .attr('src', data.src)
 .each(function() { if (this.complete) $(this).trigger('load'); });

Comment: Why you have this `.each(function() { if (this.complete) $(this).trigger('load'); });` you have only one element and load will be triggered when image is loaded. Just remove it.

Comment: As I said above: I've been advised to do this, because I've been told that the ".load" function sometimes isn't triggered as it should (can't remember if it was on Safari or Chrome)... Anyway, the rest of the code is correct ?

Comment: I never have problems with load. and load method it's jQuery thing so they probably fix the issue with browser bugs.

Comment: OK. That's what I thought too... Thanx very much for your help !

Comment: Mmmm... In fact, I've applied it to my page (link in my first post), and it doesn't work : the loader is still never applied... Now I don't understand why ?!

Comment: it work for me in Chrome. but probably should try on slower connection. You can try to preload the loader, maybe it isn't loaded when images are loading, try to add <img src="img/loading.gif" style="display:none"/> at the begining of the page.

Comment: Yes, it was just a CSS problem. Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function()
{ document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none"; }
```